# CATransform3D apply only to view and subviews except one of them

Tags: iphone, ios

I have applied `CATransform3D` to my `UIView` which has 100 subviews thus transformation is also applied to the **100 subviews**.

But, now I want to exclude only 1 subview of the 100 subviews from getting transformed. From where should I start to accomplish this?

please Help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the subviews to get transformed then you should edit the view hierarchy. You can instead have a view which is presently the parent view, add the transform, then add another view in front of transformed view,  keep the background of the new view as clear color and add the subviews to the new view view. so that you will get the desired effect.

Comment: Actually i want transformation to all the subviews except one of them which i will be highlighting and the transformation should not be applied to the highlighted subview.

Comment: In that case how about applying reverse transform of the parent transform to that particular subview?

Comment: ya i tried but i could not find any change, if u have any code snippet to do the reverse transformation plz do post it.